# Unable to install v.4.6.x - Drupal7

Tags: drupal, logs, installation, links

I tried all the day to install version **4.6.x of CiviCRM** on a brand new installation of **Drupal 7.39**, but each time I execute the installation here:

```
http://<your_drupal_home>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php
```

I get a blank page and the following error in my logs :

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Core_Config' not found in /var/www/xxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 142
```

The method I used to install is simply downloading the compressed tarball and untaring it in the folder **/var/www/xxxx/sites/all/modules/**, and this after just having completed the installation of Drupal.

My confiuration is :

- Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) server **with a private IP**
- Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
- PHP Version 5.6.7-1 (with all prerequisites except using the PHP's bundled version of PCRE for which I cannot guarantee it has the **unicode properties support**)
- Content of the VirtualHost :

> ```
>  <VirtualHost 192.168.1.203:80>
>      ServerName xxxx
>      SetEnv CODE_SITE xxxx
>      DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxx  
>      php_admin_flag  engine on
>      php_admin_value include_path "/var/www/xxxx/"
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

**EDIT 1**

> Nom I am sure that the PCRE version bundled in my PHP instance has the **unicode properties support** option enabled, since I could sucessfully execute (with no warnings) : `if(preg_match('/^\p{Arabic}+$/u', 'ﻎﺤﺤﺤﺤﺤﺣ')) echo 'OK'; else echo 'KOOOOOO'` and it displayed **OK**

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Just checking, but are you certain you downloaded the correct version of CiviCRM (for Drupal 7, not Drupal 6 or another CMS)?

Comment: also check file permissions are correct before beginning installation process...

Comment: @Laryn Yes, I installed the right version, I even installed and uninstalled it a lot of times (from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.6.8-drupal.tar.gz)

Comment: @KesakoGozaimasu Do you get the installation screen, or the error screen immediately?

Comment: @Tapash yes, I put all the permissions "rwx" for "www-data" user and group

Comment: @Laryn I get a blank page, but when I check in my logs i get the error i mentionned

Comment: @KesakoGozaimasu Any other modules installed on Drupal, or is it a blank Drupal installation?

Comment: @Laryn it's a blank Drupal installation and I have a virtualhost that is really minimalist (see the question post I just added the content of my virtualhost file)

Comment: All other notes on here are okay on your setup? http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements

Comment: You mention trying the install multiple times.  Are you sure a previous attempt didn't do a partial install and quit (for a different reason).  It sounds like it is partially installed.

Comment: @DaveD when I said "install", I simply mean I untared and decompressed the tarball of the module in /var/www/xxxx/sites/all/modules/, but the following step to complete the installation is to execute the http://<your_drupal_home>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php link and it is at that point that I get a blank page.

Comment: @Laryn yes, I already checked, and everything is conform on my server according to the link you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally succeeded to find the solution!

It was the VirtualHost's **include_path** the problem! In fact it seems that CiviCRM's install script needs to add paths in it, and if it is already set, it cannot be modified with the PHP's native function `set_include_path(void)`.

So, I only had to **comment the VirtualHost's include_path**, and it worked!

My VirtualHost looks like that now:

> ```
>  <VirtualHost 192.168.1.203:80>
>      ServerName xxxx
>      SetEnv CODE_SITE xxxx
>      DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxx  
>      php_admin_flag  engine on
>      #php_admin_value include_path "/var/www/xxxx/" => this line must be deleted
> </VirtualHost>
> ```